# PyMongo Regex on index position of query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo DB query that looks something like this

```
{ "stats.5.name" : "Some String Info" }
```

I wanted to know if  there is a way to  do this query with a regex on the number something like this

```
{ "stats.\d+.name" : "Some String Info" }
```

I tried this above and few other options but they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB natively supports array traversal. You do not need to specify the index at all.

````
{ "stats.name" : "Some String Info" }```
````